# Reorder HTML Table Cells

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, json

I have a ASP.NET page that displays a table in which every cell represents an object. This object is generated by code behind in C# sent to the page via JSON, and a Javascript function reads every object and makes a HTML cell, displaying the properties of the object inside.

I have a defined row and column quantity for each case. For example, if my total of objects is 20, the number of columns would be 4 and the number of rows would be 5.

Each object has a numeric identificator, from 1 to 20 as in the example. The objects are filled on the table from left to right, row by row, resulting in a grid like this:

```
1   2   3   4
5   6   7   8
9   10  11  12
13  14  15  16
17  18  18  20
```

The object has the following structure:

```
        public class AreaData
        {
            public string AreaId;
            public int Rows;
            public int Columns;
            public int TotalCells;
            public bool Orientation;
            public List Cells;
        }
        public class CellData
        {
            public string CellName;
            public int CellNumber;
        }
```

The basic outline of the Javascript function that makes the table is:

```
function ReturnGrid(object, settings) {
    var objId = settings["objId"];
    var objName = settings["objName"];
    if ((settings["columns"] * settings["rows"]) == object[objName].length) {
        var table = CreateFullElement("table", "id", "Table" + object[objId], "class", settings["styles"]["table_css"], "style", settings["styles"]["table_style"]);
        var tableBody = document.createElement("tbody");
        var index = 0;
        for (var j = 0; j < settings["rows"]; j++) {
            var tableRow = document.createElement("tr");
            for (var i = 0; i < settings["columns"]; i++) {
                var tableCell = CreateFullElement("td", "id", "CellName-" + object[objName][index]["CellName"], "title", object[objName][index]["CellName"], "style", settings["styles"]["td_style"]);
                object[objName][index]["ServiceTag"] = object[objName][index]["ServiceTag"].toUpperCase();
                var cellContainer;
                cellContainer = CreateFullElement("div", "id", object[objName][index]["CellName"], "class", settings["classes"]["cellContent_css"], "style", cellContent_style + "background-color:" + settings["deviceStatusColors"][object[objName][index]["DeviceStatus"]]+";");

                var cellNumText = document.createTextNode(object[objName][index]["CellNumber"]);
                cellNumContainer = CreateFullElement("div", "class", settings["classes"]["cellNumContent_css"], "style", cellNumContent_style + textcolor_Style);
                cellNumContainer.appendChild(cellNumText);
                tableCell.appendChild(cellContainer);
                tableRow.appendChild(tableCell);
                index++;
            }
        tableBody.appendChild(tableRow);
    }
        table.appendChild(tableBody);
        return table;
    }
    else {
    console.log("The values of rows and columns does not match with the length of the object");
    }
}
```

However, I want to rearrange that grid based on two conditions:

1) Fill the grid up to down

```
1   6   11  16
2   7   12  17
3   8   13  18
4   9   14  19
5   10  15  20
```

2)If required fill the grid as a mirror.

```
16  11  6   1
17  12  7   2
18  13  8   3
19  14  9   4
20  15  10  5
```

Is there a way to implement this functionality with Javascript, an already made function with Jquery? Or do I have to sort the object before stringify it to JSON?

Thanks in advance